# How to parse xml having html tags within xml tags

Tags: java, xml

I've got an xml which has html within the xml tags and i'm not able to parse as it.

When i start parsing the xml the **str** tag has html in it

[image]

can anyone help me out in extracting the html with all the tags.

Comment: What language are you using to parse the XML? PHP, JavaScript, ...?

Comment: Please show what you tried. Also, paste the actual XML, not an image of it. I can't read that at all.

Comment: Also, Rahul, please don't put "Hi" in your questions, and don't use a signature, thanks, or "any help appreciated". This is not a discussion forum, so that sort of "conversational" language is not necessary and in fact is just noise.

Comment: Can you please link to an image that doesn't have all of the XML highlighted, please?

Comment: @mc10 i''ve changed the image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a good idea to store XHTML within CDATA tags (`<![CDATA[` and `]]>`), so that it can be retrieved normally:

```xml
<str name="body">
      <![CDATA[<font face="arial" size="2"><ul><li><p align="justify">india’s first</p></li></ul></font>]]>
</str>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not the HTML but improper HTML. If this HTML is in your hand, ensure it complies with XHTML and xml parser will treat it as normal xml. However, you may otherwise use tools like "HTML Tidy" ti fix your HTML and use HTML parsers. For example:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/apmilhtml.aspx